# Sorting rows in DataTable by extracting a number

Tags: c#, regex, datatable, rows

I have a question that could maybe be simple. I have some values in a datatable column like "F-213", "F-1113/A" and so on. Is it possible to extract the number of these and sort the rows of the table by the number? I tried something like this:

```
DataTable orderedDt = _table.AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(r => int.Parse(r.Field<string>(int.Parse(Regex.Match("F-Number", @"\d+").Value))))
            .CopyToDataTable();
```

but I'm getting an Format exception.

Thank you!

Comment: better to tell what exception you are getting. and you really need datatable or data, like data row or actual column value.

Comment: I'm getting a format exception. What do you mean with really needing a datatable or data?

Comment: I just wanted to know what If I say I will return you the data row, not the data table object.  So I just wanted to know do you need data table in return or data rows??

Comment: The `Field`-extension method takes an integer which is the index of the column in the table. But you are passing the number that you have parsed.

Comment: You have `"F-Number"` in your real code? Wouldn't you probably mean something like `.OrderBy(r => int.Parse(Regex.Match(r.Field<string>("F-Number"), @"\d+").Value))`

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to sort this table somehow? I need a table that is sorted by the number in the string of the column.

Comment: so `F-xxx/A` or `F-xxx` is your column name?? and the index is not same in all the cases??  Do you have any other column in table which starts with `F-`?? except this?

Comment: The column name is "F-Number" and this column has values like "F-123", "F-23", "F-001/B", "F-345/C" and so on. Now I want to sort the table just by the numbers in the string - so "F-001/B", "F-23", "F-123", "F-345/C"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with regex as below

```
var reg = @"(\w)-(\d+)(.*)";
var orderedDataRowList = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
       .OrderBy(c => 
                   int.Parse(Regex.Match(c["F-Number"].ToString(), reg).Groups[2].Value))
       .ToList();
```

I've tested this and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx

Is the input always?

> F-Number

Comment: This is the column name